# Rendering bug? when using transparent NSWindow with SwiftUI for MacOS app

Tags: macos, swiftui, transparent, nswindow

I was developing a macOS app using SwiftUI (latest version from XCode 14.1) with the following App setup

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct DemoApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) private var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        Window("demo", id: "demo") {
            ContentView()
        }.windowStyle(.hiddenTitleBar)
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate, ObservableObject {
    @Published var active: Bool = true

    var mainWindow: NSWindow? {
        for w in NSApplication.shared.windows {
            if w.title == "demo" {
                return w
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    private func setupMainWindow() {
        
    }

    @MainActor func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_: Notification) {
        guard let w = mainWindow else {
            print("nothing to setup")
            return
        }

        w.level = .floating
        w.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
        w.isOpaque = false
        w.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
        w.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.isHidden = true
        w.standardWindowButton(.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

The content view is defined as following

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    @State var counter = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world! \(counter)").font(.system(size: 20).monospaced())
        }
        .padding().onReceive(timer) { _ in
            counter += 1
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Basically what this app does is render a transparent background window with some content on it. The content has a static image and a text that updates every second (with a counter).

The initial rendering of the window looks ok, but once the content starts update, there are two duplicated artifacts being rendered: one from the first rendering result and second from the latest rendering result. The second is overlapped on top the first one.

Here is a screenshot of the window rendering on top of a dark colored background (another window):
[image]

Here is a screenshot of the window rendering on top of a white colored background (another window):
[image]

It seems to me when the window initially launches, because it's transparent, somehow the OS or framework is adding some outline to the rendering content, as you can see from the "Hello world 0" string, there is a outline there. Maybe the framework is trying to do something to differentiate the window content from other content below it?

When the window starts updating the content, the new content will be re-drawn, but the initial captured outline is still there, leaving this weird artifact that doesn't match the current rendered content.

I've tried to disable the transparent window (with solid background or background with non-zero alpha). That will completely eliminate the issue. The added outline is only seen when the window is completely transparent. As far as I can tell, it's related to the transparent window background and the outline added to the content.

Update: using hasShadow=false won't remove the border completely (the top is still visible on black background).
[image: See the top border]

Comment: Thank you for providing a working example of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm configuring the window in a slightly different way, without the need for an `AppDelegate`, but I'm seeing the same thing. With a `backgroundColor` of `.clear`, not only is the rendering artefact apparent, also the window has no border.

Using a `NSColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.00001)` as the `backgroundColor` eliminates the rendering issue, and also shows the border correctly.

```
struct Mac_SwiftUI_testApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        
        Window("demo", id: "demo") {
            ContentView()
                .task {
                    NSApplication.shared.windows.forEach { window in
                        guard window.identifier?.rawValue == "demo" else { return  }
                        
                        window.standardWindowButton(.zoomButton)?.isHidden = true
                        window.standardWindowButton(.closeButton)?.isHidden = true
                        window.standardWindowButton(.miniaturizeButton)?.isHidden = true
                        window.backgroundColor = NSColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.00001)
                        window.isOpaque = false
                        window.level = .floating
                    }
                }
        }
        .windowStyle(.hiddenTitleBar)
    }
}
```

**With `backgroundColor = .clear`**

[image]

**With `backgroundColor = NSColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.00001)`**

[image]

After trying a few things out, I found that setting

```
window.hasShadow = false
```

will fix your problem. It also removes the top "line" on the clear window

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The non-zero background can make it transparent, however it comes with two things I don't want to have:
1) The border of the window. Yes, I don't want to have the window border at all
2) The when the app overlay on top of content that has similar color as the content, the content is not visible

The nice thing about the original source code I posted is that swiftui somehow intelligently adds a border to my content (the text) so that it can always be seen. I believe this is a bug in the swiftui framework

Comment: I think the overlay issue can be solved by add my own way of rendering the outline of the content. Regarding the window border, I hope there is a way to hide it when the background is non-zero.

Comment: Did you see the end of my answer? The window border can be hidden by `window.hasShadow = false`

Comment: Yes. I tried that on my macos but somehow the top border is still there. My OS is in dark mode BTW. The top line is definitely not very obvious when the background is white. Let me upload the screenshot to the original post so you can see.

Comment: You're right! I just tested it in dark mode and the faint top border is still there. How weird is that, because I definitely can't see it in light mode.